# Change the rowheight for a particular index in a section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have been setting the cell heights for my tableview with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        return 100
    case 1:
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        return  UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```

With this, for all the rows in section 1, the rowheight is set to 100. Now, I would like to change the row height of a particular row to set to 0 (i.e. make it hidden) on button click.

I have tried:

```
tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(item: selectedIndex, section: 1))?.isHidden
```

Although the cell is hidden, I am left with a blank cell occupying the row height.

So I think I should be changing the row height to 0.

P.S. I know this can be achieved by removing the particular row from the model and using *deleteRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], 
           with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation)* But I do not want to change the model. How can this be done?

Comment: in the method func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat, return 0.00001 for your specific cell because returning 0 would give the cell a default height

Comment: Why don't you use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` only and play with `constraints` to change the height of all the cells according the `subviews` in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flag to check if you clicked the button. Then reload the table after button click.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return indexPath.section == 0 ? buttonClicked && indexPath.row == 0 ? CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude : 100 : UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Longer, more readable version :-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

switch indexPath.section {
case 0:
    if buttonClicked && indexPath.row = rowIndex //index of required row which you can find out and store in a variable wherever necessary {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    }
    return 100
case 1:
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    return  UITableViewAutomaticDimension
default:
    return 0
}
}
```

Comment: Doing this, all the cells within that section would get the leastNormalMagnitude height. But I want only for the first cell.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik, i wouldn't sacrifice readability for lesser code.

Comment: I prefer the long version.